# WordPress Post Meta Like Query Does Not Recognize Second Like Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, full-text-search

Currently I have built a search feature that takes in 3 variables. One is the term to search, second is the province (custom field), and the third is the city (custom field).

Currently the way it works is as follows:

```
$province = $wp_query->query_vars['province'];
$city = $wp_query->query_vars['city'];

if ( !empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) && !empty( $province ) && !empty( $city ) ) {   
    $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'province' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $province . "') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'city' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $city . "'))";
} else if ( !empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) && !empty( $province ) ) {   
    $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'province' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%" . $province . "%') ";
} else if ( !empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) && !empty( $city ) ) {   
    $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'city' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%" . $city . "%') ";
}
```

If I try to search by term and province, the results I expect are returned. When I then try to also search by city (3 parameters) all posts by province no results are returned. If I change:

Has AND

```
$where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'province' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $province . "') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'city' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $city . "'))";
```

HAS OR

```
$where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'province' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $province . "') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'city' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '" . $city . "'))";
```

Then results are returned, except the query is not picking up the city LIKE statement and is showing all cities instead of just drilling down to the specific city.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where are you getting this syntax from?  `$wpdb` usage is usually something like `$wpdb->get_results(QUERY)`, not using `$wpdb` in the actual query..

Comment: $wpdb->postmeta outputs the table

Answer (score 1):

You have to join 3 times wp_postmeta to wp_post (also group by post id after joining) then your query will work. Now each post is in one row and it has one meta_key and one meta_value. (You put all conditions with AND operator it will nor work it will work only with OR but I guess you want post which has all search terms).

Regards